# Tide and Trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

I have a tide guide that gives me four readings for the day - 2 high tides and two low tides. This means it completes two full revolutions within a day. What I'm having trouble with is taking the four measurments and making a graph and equation of the entire function for that specific day.

One example is...
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
6{:}00\text{am} & 17.1\text{ft}\\\hline
11{:}17\text{am} & 11.8\text{ft}\\\hline 
16{:}01\text{pm} & 15.7\text{ft}\\\hline 
23{:}22\text{pm} & 1.0\text{ft}
\end{array}$$

How do I use these to complete the sine or cosine function?
 These would be random points on the graph which follows the $f(x) = a \sin(bx + c)+ d$ general form.

Comment: @Stefan4024: *Just* inserting dollar signs does not always improve the formatting of the post.

Comment: The quoted numbers don’t look like high and low tides for the day. Usually a tide table gives nothing but times of high and low tides, plus the predicted depths at those times. It’s inconceivable to me that one low tide in a day would be only $1.0$ feet and the other would be $11.8$ feet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your table of data gives you four values for $(x,f(x))$, once you decide where $0$ is. Suppose we let $x$ represent hours after midnight. Then you've got the data points $(6,17.1), (11.283,11.8), (16.017,15.7), (23.367,1)$

You want to determine the constants $a,b,c,d$, and you have four data points to work with. Plug each data point into your general form equation, and you'll get four equations in four unknowns. The equations might not be easy to solve without mechanical assistance, however. Typing them into something like Wolfram Alpha would probably get you a numerical solution, anyway.

Does this help?

ETA:
Let's write down the details. The resulting equations are:

$a\sin(6b + c) + d = 17.1\\
a\sin(11.283b + c) + d = 11.8\\
a\sin(16.017b + c) + d = 15.7\\
a\sin(23.367b + c) + d = 1$

I don't know a way to solve for $a,b,c$ and $d$ from those equations. :/  I tried feeling them into Wolfram Alpha, but it gave up after thinking for a few seconds. You might try searching for information on "fitting a sine curve to data", and there might be a built-in function in Excel that will do this.

Sorry that I can't be more help.

Comment: Thank you so much! but in the general equation, a is your amplitude (height)  b is your period of phase c is your horizontal translation and d is your vertical translation. However, when i plug in the values i have, I don't know how to get the amplitude or any of the others? Is it too much to ask of you to help me work it out and graph it, using the equation we find?

Comment: IF (and I am not sure wether the IF is correct) it were an exact sine wave then your high should happen at $\pi/2$ and low at $-\pi/2$.

Comment: @Maesumi, that would only be true if we knew b=1 and c=0. In this case, we don't know either.

Comment: I don't know what the intent of the exercise was (a problem from a textbook, perhaps?), but this answer is an incorrect approach to fit a curve to a twice-daily tide. The real world just does not work that way at all; the answer by Andrew is a much better fit. (Still, I suppose it is possible that the idea in the book _may_ have been to fit a sinusoidal curve to the data; I've seen some fairly horrible "real world" exercises in math books.)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to solve this system of equations with a function of the form given. When plotting the points, observe that any sine or cosine function that has a minimum of 11.8 cannot possibly reach a value of 1.

It is possible however, to write a linear combination of such functions up to a constant that give values very close to those desired. In fact, Fourier analysis allows one to construct such a linear combination for any set of points. Consider the function given by $$ f(x)=9 \cos \left[\frac{2 \pi}{44}(x-10)\right]+3.5\cos \left[\frac{2 \pi}{11}(x-5.5)\right]+6.3$$

[image: tides]

Then $f(6)=17.08$, $f(11.283)=11.73$, $f(16.017)=15.7$, and $f(23.367)=1.07$. These fit the values desired within a margin of error less than an inch.

Comment: I think this is a huge improvement over the accepted answer, although it predicts high tides at 6:06 and 15:39 and low tides at 11:11 and 23:09 (that is, the derivative is zero at $x = 6.10609, 11.1908, 15.6543, 23.1545$ -- see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+d%289%2Acos%282%2Api%2A%28x-10%29%2F44%29%2B3.5%2Acos%282%2Api%2A%28x-5.5%29%2F11%29%2B6.3%29%2Fdx+%3D+0+for+0%3Cx%3C24). Actual tide data has more than two components, and IIRC their periods are not related by simple ratios, but we obviously don't have enough information to make a very realistic model here.

Comment: @DavidK I'll spend some time tomorrow finding a curve that fits exactly, however I think this is sufficient given that no solution exists with the form given by the OP. I merely wanted to show that the data could be represented so I just guessed and checked to get this close.

Comment: Actually I think you did nice work here, and I upvoted it already. I don't yet know if it even is possible to do better than you have done with any reasonably simple assumptions. The fault is in the problem statement more than in your calculations (You could look up the periods of the main components of the tides, and _maybe_ get a "better" fit that way, but that would be cheating in a sense.)